# Number Format of int variable while debuging in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, hex

How to change number format of int type variable while debugging in c# visual studio. its appear in `0xffffffff` this format and its shows wrong values.

Comment: right click on the variable, uncheck "show hexadecimal"

Answer (score 2):

- Debug your code.
- Go to your [local window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290840%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or [watch window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290869%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).
- Right click the variable.
- You will see Hexadecimal Display.

[image]